# Possible way to increase joins performance to SQL query for Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having a query whose performance is really bad, like it takes more than 15 min. to get 6000 rows worth of data. I'm not sure if this is caused by my joins or bad query or my schema.

Can someone please help me, it would be very super helpful to know if there is a performance issue. What are the best steps to follow? Which part of my query is causing poor performance?

```
WITH ship AS (
SELECT
    "ORDER"
FROM
    historymaster hm
WHERE
    --datetimecreated BETWEEN TO_char(:startdate,'MM-DD-YYYY') AND 
TO_char(:enddate +1 ,'MM-DD-YYYY')
    datetimecreated BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startdate,'MM-DD-YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE(:enddate,'MM-DD-YYYY')
    AND   "OBJECT" = 'OBORDLINE'
    AND   hm.package = ' '
    AND   actionmodifier IS NULL
    AND   "ACTION" = 'SHIP'
),cpt_time AS (
SELECT
    unique(outboundorder),
    TO_CHAR(shipdatetime,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS cpt,
    routingcomments1,
    routingcomments2
FROM
    history_outbound_order_master
WHERE
    outboundorder IN (
        SELECT
            "ORDER"
        FROM
            ship
    )
    AND   routingcomments2 IS NOT NULL
),transations AS (
SELECT
    "ORDER",
    datetimecreated,
    datecreated,
    TO_CHAR(datetimecreated,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS ship_complete_time,
    actualquantity,
    "ACTION",
    warehouse AS site
FROM
    historymaster hm
WHERE
--datetimecreated BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startdate,'MM-DD-YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE(:enddate,'MM-DD-YYYY')
    -- ship complete 
    "ORDER" IN (
        SELECT
            "ORDER"
        FROM
            ship
    )
    AND   (
        (
            "OBJECT" = 'OBORDLINE'
            AND   hm.package = ' '
            AND   actionmodifier IS NULL
            AND   "ACTION" = 'SHIP'
        )
        OR -- pick 
         (
            "ACTION" = 'PICK'
            AND   "OBJECT" = 'OBO'
            AND   "CLASS" = 'INVE'
            AND   actualquantity != 0
            AND   substr(ordertype,1,1) = 'N'
        )
        OR -- Order drop 
         (
            "ACTION" = 'DNLD'
            AND   "OBJECT" = 'OBORDLINE'
            AND   actionmodifier IS NULL
            AND   reasoncode = '00'
        )
        OR --label request
         (
            "ACTION" = 'REQUEST'
            AND   "OBJECT" = 'LABEL'
            AND   "CLASS" = 'ADDR'
        )
        OR    (
            "ACTION" = 'LOAD'
            AND   "OBJECT" = 'OBO'
            AND   "CLASS" = 'INVE'
        )
    )
) SELECT
"ORDER",
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN "ACTION" = 'DNLD' THEN ship_complete_time
    END
) AS order_drop_time,
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN "ACTION" = 'REQUEST' THEN ship_complete_time
    END
) AS label_request_time,
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN "ACTION" = 'PICK' THEN ship_complete_time
    END
) AS pick_time,
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN "ACTION" = 'LOAD' THEN ship_complete_time
    END
) AS load_time,
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN "ACTION" = 'SHIP' THEN ship_complete_time
    END
) AS ship_com_time,
cpt,
routingcomments1,
routingcomments2
FROM
transations left
JOIN cpt_time ON "ORDER" = outboundorder

GROUP BY
"ORDER",
routingcomments1,
routingcomments2,
cpt
```

Comment: You have to provide more details like execution plan, table structures and indexes defined on them etc.

Comment: The use of cascading WITH clauses looks over-engineered. What purpose does that serve? Did you start with the simplest query which might work?

Comment: YES I tried without with but it took me longer to run

Comment: How long it takes to *get* 6000 rows isn't really relevant. If it has to read, join and filter 6 billion rows (for example) then maybe 15 minutes is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the column are not uniform distributed,  ensure column statistics  are gathered.

If every sub-select for itself runs fast, add the hint /*+ materialize */ to the selects to ensure it runs as planned.